# How to put multiple values in keys and from sorted lists in Python?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

How to make dict out of 2 lists and put multiple values in keys?

I've ended up with two lists in order

> time = ['11:00', '18:19', '18:19', '00:00', '08:01', '18:19', '00:00']
>
> activity = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'a', 'f', 'g']

I've tried to put everything together with dict(zip(time, value)), but it didn't quite work out

My goal is to get dict with keys as time and values as activity
So that:

> {'11:00': 'a'
>
> '18:19': 'b', 'c', 'f'
>
> '00:00': 'd', 'g'
>
> '08:01': 'a'}

```
def get_time_activity(input_filename):
    file = open(input_filename, mode='r')
    input_string = file.read()
    hour = []
    minute = []
    activity = []
    for match in re.finditer(r"(\d+)\D(\d+)\s+(\w+)", input_string):
        hour.append(match.group(1))
        minute.append(match.group(2))
        activity.append(match.group(3))

    time24 = zip(hour, minute)
    result = list(time24)
    time = [':'.join(r) for r in result]
    return time, activities
```

Comment: Your goal is not valid Python code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple for loop using [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=zip#zip) + [dict.setdefault](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) will do it:

```
time = ['11:00', '18:19', '18:19', '00:00', '08:01', '18:19', '00:00']
activity = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'a', 'f', 'g']

result = {}
for ti, ai in zip(time, activity):
    result.setdefault(ti, []).append(ai)

print(result)
```

**Output**

```
{'11:00': ['a'], '18:19': ['b', 'c', 'f'], '00:00': ['d', 'g'], '08:01': ['a']}
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to convert to a DataFrame and then groupby:

```
import pandas as pd

# setup 
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "time": ['11:00', '18:19', '18:19', '00:00', '08:01', '18:19', '00:00'],
    "activity": ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'a', 'f', 'g']
})

# logic
df.groupby("time")["activity"].apply(list).to_dict()
```

Output:

```
{'00:00': ['d', 'g'], '08:01': ['a'], '11:00': ['a'], '18:19': ['b', 'c', 'f']}
```